# Redirecionar para uma html com Spring Boot

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

Eu estou começando a criar aplicações  com o Spring Boot + Gradle, porém ao configurar o Controller, não consigo redirecionar uma url a um arquivo html ou jsp.

Minha application está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu Controller:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A pagina exibida pelo http://localhost:8080/ é uma página em branco escrito: login.html e não exibindo a html que eu coloquei na pasta static.

Vi alguns casos parecidos, mas todas as respostas que encontrei não funcionaram, então achei melhor abrir um novo tópico.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver dessa forma:

**Criando uma RequestMapping na Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/")
   public ModelAndView index(){
   return new ModelAndView("index");
}
```

Diferente do seu, ele retorna um `ModelAndView`, que irá puxar a página de dentro de `resources/templates/`.

**Criando uma Dependency no pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

E para finalizar, ter a página `index.html` dentro de `resources/templates/`.

Comment: Muito bom amigo, obrigado, desta forma funcionou perfeitamente p/ mim!

Answer (score 0):

Faça a seguinte alteração no seu endpoint

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "login";
}
```